# How to create listview in fragment that is part of navigation drawer

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent, navigation-drawer

Listed below is a fragment that is in a navigation drawer which I am attempting to make a listview in. However there is an error on those 2 lines, the one that starts with setlistadapter and listview. It says it is an error there on those. How would I go about fixing it.

Error:(29, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter)

Error:(30, 25) error: cannot find symbol method getListView()

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

```
public class First extends Fragment { 

View myView;

@Nullable

String[] courses = {"1", "2", "3"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courses));
    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg1, long arg2) {
            switch (arg1) {
                case 0:
                    Intent myIntent0 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Test.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent0, 0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Test.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Test.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.math, container, false);
    return myView;

}
}

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: What is the error. paste the logcat.

Comment: Error:(29, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)

Error:(30, 25) error: cannot find symbol method getListView()

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: @Tauqir I put it up top now

Answer (score 1):

Both `setListAdapter` and `getListView` are methods in the `ListFragment` class, but you are only extending `Fragment`.

You should read up on [layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and [creating a navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). In the xml layout you'll most likely want to wrap a `ListView` inside the nav-drawer.

Comment: How exactly would I do that

Comment: Please read the links. The second one literally has a ListView nested inside a DrawerLayout.

Comment: Definitely will. Thanks

Comment: If this solved your issue, please mark my answer as the solution.